# Issue with slider bars not adding together the correct value to then switch images

Tags: jquery, html, jscript

The following code is meant to add all the slider bars totals together and then switch images depending what level has been reached. At the moment it only appears to work with switching to the first level, any higher than 50 and the image doesnt change. What have i missed?

```
       <script>
       $(function() {
      $( ".slider" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
 var total = 0;
$('.slider').each( function() {
    total += $(this).slider('value');
});

var img = 'img1.jpg';
if( total<=100 ) img = 'img1.jpg';
else if( total>=200 ) img = 'img2.jpg';
else if( total>=300 ) img = 'img3.jpg';
else if( total>=400 ) img = 'img4.jpg';
else if( total>=500 ) img = 'img5.jpg';

 ;

   $('#amount-img').attr( 'src', 'img/'+img );
  }
 });
   });


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of your conditions:

```
if( total>=150 ) img = 'img1.jpg';
else if( total>=100 ) img = 'img3.jpg';
else if( total>=50 ) img = 'img2.jpg';
```

otherwise the first one was true for all cases

Comment: Thanks, to be clearer. what I really want to get to is change the image every 100 value. I've updated the code above with my effort, but still appear to be missing the point...

Comment: @Dano007 yes you missed the point, the largest value should be the first condition, then work your way to the lowest value, so start with >= 500, >=400, >=300, etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your first condition in the if statement is being met and is then skipping the remaining conditions.

eg. the number 120 is larger than 50, so the if statement ends there.

This will fix the problem:

```
$(function () {
    $(".slider").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var total = 0;
            $('.slider').each(function () {
                total += $(this).slider('value');
            });

            var img = 'img1.jpg';

            if (total >= 150) img = 'img1.jpg';             
            else if (total >= 100) img = 'img3.jpg';
            else if (total >= 50) img = 'img2.jpg';

            $('#amount-img').attr('src', 'img/' + img);
        }
    });
});
```